# Vue.js Note that mounted does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, hook

Can someone please explain notice below from VUE doc https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted ?

> Note that mounted does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted.

I have tested mounting children and subchildren but both are always mounted before root/app component, so it is safe to use "mounted" without $nextTick to access DOM. Children and subchildren components can access DOM element from root/app template although it is mounted after children. On the other way root/app can also access DOM elements in children templates. Consider this example...

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <child></child>
  <span id="root"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var subchild = {
    template: `<div>SUBCHILD<span id="subchild"></span></div>`,
    mounted() {
      console.log("Mounted SUBCHILD", document.getElementById('root'));
    }
  };
  
  var child = {
    template: `<div>CHILD<span id="child"></span><subchild></subchild></div>`,
    components : { subchild },
    mounted() {
      console.log("Mounted CHILD", document.getElementById('root'));
    }
  };
  
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components : { child },
    data() {
      return { message: 'APP' };
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log("Mounted APP", document.getElementById('root'), document.getElementById('child'), document.getElementById('subchild'));
    }
  
  })
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecobyxrn/

Output in console...

> Mounted SUBCHILD [object HTMLSpan...] [object HTMLSpan...] [object HTMLSpan...]
>
> Mounted CHILD [object HTMLSpan...] [object HTMLSpan...] [object HTMLSpan...]
>
> Mounted APP [object HTMLSpan...] [object HTMLSpan...] [object HTMLSpan...]

So in my case I do not understand that VUE notice. Can someone show use case that children are mounted later then root/app? I think VUE doc is very poor and does not explain it very well. I also tried delayed mount of root/app by commenting out `el: '#app'` + adding `setTimeout(function() { app.$mount('#app'); }, 2000);` but result is the same.

In addition see this image...
[image: VUE.js mounted hooks parent + child]

Image source: https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f

At source page someone in comment warns image author about mentioned VUE notice but does not explain it. It seems that everyone knows about that notice but nobody explains it.

Comment: You are not doing anything asynchronously. Change your simple example to use Async Components or load components using ES6 imports and you may find a different story. Your use case is too basic to run into the loading delay.

Comment: The fiddle in your comment now loads the children AFTER the App. Demonstrating exactly what the docs state. (I do agree, by the way, that the docs could be clearer about that point!).

Comment: @thanksd In my code I have order Mounted SUBCHILD, Mounted CHILD, Mounted APP. Your order is exactly the opposite Mounted APP, Mounted CHILD, Mounted SUBCHILD and there are also not available some span elements. @RandyCasburn I have just tested my sample using ES6 import/export for components and there is no difference. Difference is only in case async component such as in @thanksd`s jsfiddle. So when SPA app does not use async components (each app I work on) I do not need to bother with @nextTick callback in mounted hook at all? I think that VUE doc should mention this important difference.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, you were correct, I was misreading the log output.

Comment: @mikep, correct, your synchronously-loaded components fire their `mounted` hooks from the subchild up, because each component is waiting for the child to be loaded before mounting. The async-loaded components in my example load from the parent down, because the children have not resolved yet and the `mounted` hook fires anyway, because it has the Promise that they will resolve. But, as you mentioned, those async components can't be referenced in the parents `mounted` hook, which is what the Vue docs are describing.

Comment: @mikep, if you are not loading components asynchronously, I don't believe there is another scenario in which you would need to use `$nextTick` to be sure the child components have mounted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RandyCasburn mentioned, components can be loaded asynchronously. Each property of the `components` object can either be given a component definition object, or a `Promise` which eventually resolves with a component definition object. So, in these cases, it could be that the parent component's `mounted` hook gets called before the asynchronously-loaded children have finished loading.

As a simple test of this, you could change your base component's `component` object to load the `child` component after a delay:

```
components: {
  child: () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(child)
    }, 2000)
  }) 
}
```

You'll see that the reference to child component in the `mounted` hook is `null` when it fires.

It does seem unhelpful that the Vue docs do not mention this as a potential cause for the scenario they are warning against. And, other than using async components, I can't think of another scenario where a child component would not be mounted when the parent's `mounted` hook is fired.

---

Here's a full example using your code:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

var subchild = {
  template: `<div>SUBCHILD<span id="subchild"></span></div>`,
  mounted() {
    console.log("Mounted SUBCHILD", document.getElementById('root'), document.getElementById('child'), document.getElementById('subchild'));
  }
};

var child = {
  template: `<div>CHILD<span id="child"></span><subchild></subchild></div>`,
  components : { subchild: () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(subchild)
    }, 2000)
  }) },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Mounted CHILD", document.getElementById('root'), document.getElementById('child'), document.getElementById('subchild'));
  }
};

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components : { child: () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(child)
    }, 2000)
  }) },
  data() {
    return { message: 'APP' };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Mounted APP", document.getElementById('root'), document.getElementById('child'), document.getElementById('subchild'));
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <child ref="child"></child>
  <span id="root"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Btw @thanksd I have added $nextTick() to your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/odskrycn/ and "Mounted APP" is still logged as first. Now I do not undersand that VUE doc notice at all. Doc recommends to use $nextTick() to ensure all children are mounted. We concluded that notice is probably related to async components. But $nextTick() does not solve it. So what that notice mean? Btw how doveloper knows when are all children components (including async) mounted?

Comment: Hmm yeah, you are correct. I'm at a loss. I'm not aware of any other situation where the child component would not already be mounted. But as you've shown, using `$nextTick` is certainly not helpful in the case of async components.